# Is there a way to delay execution of an Axios request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to delay the execution of an Axios request. So far I've tried to use set timeout to delay the request with no luck. Ideally what should be happening is when a request hits this route it will read the status code from the body and then send the axios post below after 10 minutes if the code is 0. This all works fine but it is sending instantly. How should I go about this?

```
//STATUS CAKE ROUTE
app.post('/status', (req, res) => {
res.sendStatus(200);
console.log('recieved');

let Name = req.body.Name;
let Code = req.body.StatusCode;

console.log(Code);
//How we're handling status code 0 for a downed server
if (Code === '0') {

    //Create reboot prompt
    const RebootPrompt = {
        channel: '******',
        blocks: [
            {
                type: 'section',
                text: {
                    type: 'plain_text',
                    text: `${Name}`,
                    emoji: true,
                },
            },
            {
                type: 'actions',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        text: {
                            type: 'plain_text',
                            emoji: true,
                            text: 'Reboot!',
                        },
                        style: 'primary',
                        value: `${Name},true`,
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'button',
                        text: {
                            type: 'plain_text',
                            emoji: true,
                            text: 'Leave it alone',
                        },
                        style: 'danger',
                        value: 'false',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    };
    //Send the prompt to reboot if we get a 0 status code to the channel.
    setTimeout(() => {
        axios.post(
            'https://hooks.slack.com/services/********/********/**********',
            RebootPrompt
        );
    }, 600000);
}
});
```

Comment: The above code should be fine and execute after 600 seconds, what happens when you run this?

Comment: It still runs instantly.

Comment: Well, how are you invoking this? Is it wrapped in a function and then post some click are you calling this?

Comment: The code above is inside of an if statement that will run if it's true.

Comment: Could you post the condition as well to assist you better?

Comment: I've added the full snippet with the condition. The post request is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(async function() {
    try {
      let res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");//This executes after 3 seconds.
      let resJson = await res.json();
      alert(resJson.data.length)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  }, 3000); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then the api gets triggered.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
</body>

</html>
```